# No clonning states that one cannot clone any arbitrary given state. But can we have a device that can create same superposition state repetatively?

Tags: no-cloning-theorem

No clonning states that one cannot clone any arbitrary given state. But can we have a device that can create same superposition state repetatively

Comment: If the state is known , then it can be recreated by constructing the circuit that produces it , but if the state is random then I don't think it can be created because once the state is measured it will collapse to either $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$

Comment: You can measure the state repeatedly and with quantum tomography reconstruct the probability amplitudes. Knowing them, you can prepare the state. This is however exponentially costly process.